# PL/SQL: Need to create conditional calculated columns in the select query

Tags: plsql, conditional-statements, where-clause, calculated-columns

I am trying to create conditional calculated columns in my select query. The logic is given below

```
   Select  FT.NAME, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT PAGEID) as Total_Forms, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT PAGEID WHERE FT."Column1?" =1) as Expected_forms,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PAGEID WHERE FT."Column1?" =1 AND FT."FORM STATUS" in ('C','I') as Actual_forms,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATAPAGEID WHERE FT."IS FORM EXPECTED1?" =1)/
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATAPAGEID WHERE FT."IS FORM EXPECTED1?" =1 AND FT."FORM STATUS" in ('C','I'))
     as Percentage
   FROM
       (Subquery) FT
   Group by FT.Name
```

I have tried various combinations but nothing has worked so far. The output would look like this

```
  name      Total_forms   Expected_forms   Actual Forms  Percentage
  abc        943          811              781           96.54%
  pqr        900          800              600           75.00%
```

I am unable to however formulate this in PL/SQL query. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is wrong:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT PAGEID WHERE FT."Column1?" =1) as Expected_forms,
```

Use [CASE Expression](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language/SELECT:_Case_Expression) instead:

```
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT PAGEID) as Total_Forms, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN FT."Column1?" =1 THEN PAGEID END ) as Expected_forms,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN FT."Column1?" =1 AND FT."FORM STATUS" in ('C','I') 
                   THEN PAGEID END ) as Actual_forms,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN FT."IS FORM EXPECTED1?" =1 THEN DATAPAGEID  END)/
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN FT."IS FORM EXPECTED1?" =1 AND FT."FORM STATUS" in ('C','I') 
                   THEN DATAPAGEID  END) as Percentage
   FROM
       (Subquery) FT
   Group by FT.Name
```